# How to click an input type=checkbox from an aria-expanded menu using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

i have been trying to click an input as type: checkbox but it doesn't seem to work. I need to press one of the size options but when i expand the size-picker-form using this piece of code:
`sizelistspot = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="picker-trigger"]'))) sizelistspot = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="picker-trigger"]').click()`
and then use this piece of code to check if the form is located:

`sizelist = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'size-picker-form'))) print('I found the size menu!!!')`
I watch it run because i run non-headless and i see the dropdown menu expand so then i try to select a size with this piece of code:

`sizechoice = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'size-picker-JOC12N001-A180150000').click() print('I selected the size!!!')`
But i recieve the error: 'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable' Why can't i click the size whilst i can manually? And what is the right way to do it. This is the link to the site: https://www.zalando.nl/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-hoog-joc12n001-a18.html I am still a beginner so there is a big chance there are some mistakes in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//div[./*[@id='size-picker-JOC12N001-A180150000']]
```

Just click the div that contains that id instead the input tag has 0x0 size and doesn't seem to be interactable.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,60)                                 
driver.get('https://www.zalando.nl/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-hoog-joc12n001-a18.html')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#uc-btn-accept-banner"))).click()
sizelistspot = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="picker-trigger"]')))
sizelistspot.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[./*[@id="size-picker-JOC12N001-A180150000"]]'))).click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: An input contains the id, how should i formulate it in my code? /html/body/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[15] This is the XPATH from the div that contains the input. but if i use this XPATH it gives me the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. But i don't understand why since it can locate the id but not the XPATH which contains the id, that doesn't make sense right?

Comment: You need to wait for elements to appear and such.

Comment: Thanks it worked! If you make a xpath yourself do you always have to use "//div[./*"?

Comment: Not really no that xpath means click the div that has an element with id. div/ this has id but click the element who is the parent.

Comment: Oh ok i get it. Is it also possible to click a div on the span you see in the list like 50.5? Because i noticed every shoe has a different id of course so then it wouldn't really work.

Comment: //div[@role='presentation'][.//span[.='50.5']] just with size>